# Capturing Each Skipped Record - Copy Data Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm doing a large-scale project with multiple pipelines, millions of records per pipeline. I'm trying to develop a generic skipped row capture process.

What I need to do is: for every source row skipped due to any error encountered on the attempted load, I want to capture a key column value from the row and write it to a distinct log file (or separate DB table row). This can't be summary data: for each individual row that fails, I need to capture the row key from that row so we can review/re-load later (I will add in system variable values to identify pipeline, component, time stamp, etc). Pipeline must complete with all successful rows loaded, all unsuccessful rows logged.

This is no-brainer functionality in most ETL tools; I *have* to be overlooking something in ADF, because I can't find a way to do this. Appreciate any/all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Fault tolerance and choose Skip incompatible rows option. It will skip the incompatible rows between source and target store during copy data. e.g. type and field mismatch or PK violation.

Then you can enable session log and choose Warning log level in copy activity to log skipped rows. Finally, you can save your log file in  Azure Storage or Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-log

Comment: Steve - can we give custom names for these log files as well?

Comment: @azuresnowflake1 No, we can only specify to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. With your first copy activity, check the fault tolerance option in 'settings' to log skipped fault rows.
2. Make sure to place your rows key column, as the first in the mapping definition.
3. Get the copy activity `logFilePath` from the activity output into a variable
4. Add another copy activity to load skipped rows into relational table
   it source path will be the variable holds `logFilePath`
5. Set the file path type to: 'Wildcard file path'
6. Keep the 'Wildcard file path' empty
7. - Will be the value in Wildcard file name
8. Make sure that the delimited file dataset escape character is set to quotations.
9. The `OperationItem` field of the lg file holds your record fields seperated by `,`; because we placed the `rowID` first on mapping, it will appear first in `OperationalItem` as well.

Goodluck

Comment: Can you review items number 5-7? The guidance there isn't especially clear.